# Recursive function in counting words

Tags: java, recursion

Hello can someone show me a java code on how to use recursive function in counting words in a sentence? It's kinda hard for me to understand recursion maybe a code will help me understand thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, but questions here are reserved for specific questions, this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: believe me. A code would not.

Comment: `Haskell` is a good program language to learn recursion in an easy way, if it's recursion your problem, u can see it more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you asked for:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Sample class to demonstrate recursion
 * @author vmarche
 */
public class WordCount {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        // Infinite loop
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            try {
                String input = keyboard.readLine();
                int count = countWords(input);
                System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Counts the words in a sentence recursively
     * @param sentence      The input sentence
     * @return              The number of words
     */
    public static int countWords (String sentence) {

        if (sentence.isEmpty())
        return 0;

        // Find the first index of a space
        int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");

        // If space exists, return count of sub-sentence
        if (space != -1)
            return 1 + countWords(sentence.substring(space + 1));
        // Else space does not exist, return 1
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is whats exactly on my mind!! but i dont know how to put it in code thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a very unusual use case for a recursive function but the basic idea would be along the lines of:

```
def countWordsIn (sentence):
    if sentence.hasNoMoreWords():
        return 0
    return 1 + countWords (sentence.stripFirstWord())
```

All you really have to learn is that recursion involves stating your problem in terms of a simpler case (such as the word count in a sentence being one added to the word count of that sentence without the first word) and having a terminating condition (where there are no more words left).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RecursionDemonstration{
    public static int numWords(String sentence)
    {
        int i = sentence.indexOf(' ');
        if (i == -1) return 1;                          //Space is not found
        return 1+numWords(sentence.substring(i+1));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numWords("Hello this is a test"));
    }

}
```

The concept is to slowly reduce the size of a problem until it becomes so trivial that you can solve it directly.
All you need is a base case and a relationship between problems and sub-problems.
(PS: My code won't work for empty strings or sentences ending in spaces. It can be fixed easily, but I didn't for simplicity's sake).

Comment: can you explain how this works a diagram would be better

Comment: The number of words in a sentence is: 1 + (the number of words in the sentence excluding the first word). This is a **recursive definition.**